# I cut a wire too short, where there needs to be 6 inches of wire coming into the box. What can I do to fix it to be up to electrical code?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, code-compliance

I didn't have extra wire to connect a bundle of neutrals to a switch, so I cut some off of an existing neutral wire that had some extra wire. I then found out about the electrical code that requires 6 inches of wire from the entrance to a box to the bundle of wires. I think I have about 3 or 4 inches right now, but I did buy some white THHN cable.

It will be easy to switch out the jumper wire that goes from the bundle to the switch with a longer wire, but what can I do about the wire that enters the box and goes into the bundle to get it up to code? Would splicing it be better than just leaving it?

Answer (score 2):

If this was new construction and an inspector saw this, he's make you pull new wire. Since it's existing, wire nut some extra wire onto the short piece so you have room to work with the switch. Never, ever cut wire in a junction box. you never know when you might need it.

Comment: I will definitely keep that in mind in the future. Is there a suggested method to splice them? Should I solder them together or is twisting them together with electrical tape sufficient?

Comment: @FrankGeda solder or electrical tape have no place in your home's wiring.  You can use twist on wire nuts (after twisting the wires with pliers) or you can use push-on connectors which are gaining popularity.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Okay noted. I was looking at a western union splice with shrink wrap tubing. The wire is coming into the box and already going into a wire nut (where a bundle is). From there I can add as much wire as needed to go from the bundle to the neutral terminal on the switch, but it's my understanding there needs to be 6 inches from where it enters the box to any pigtail or wire nut. If it's already going to a wire nut should I just leave it?

Comment: At this point, you should just leave it.  Another splice just crowds the box.  As JACK says, this code is more for new installs.  The code wants to give you plenty of room to make a strong, proper connection.  The shorter the wire, the harder that is.

Comment: @FrankGeda "solder them together or is twisting them together with electrical tape sufficient?" Whatever made you say that, fire it.  No, you never "improvise" or "freestyle" *anything* in AC mains electrical.  You did the right thing by asking the right way.  Wire nuts, lever nuts, Alumiconns etc. Western Union splices haven't been used since the Knob and Tube days, and you don't have nearly enough wire anyway.  By the by, solder splices were done by the *master electrician* - the apprentice was not allowed to.

Comment: Another rule of thumb is anything *that is time-consuming* is not modern practice.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I read too many things online saying that you're fine twisting things together or soldering things and covering it with electrical tape, so I'm definitely glad I asked.

Comment: @FrankGeda  That's allowed for low voltage stuff and line voltage circuit boards but not household/commercial mains wiring.  Be careful of what you read on the internet and watch on you tube.